# libcjson.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux

My OS is Centos 7

when I run `ldconfig -p` , I can see that "libcjson.so.1.5.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libcjson.so.1.5.7"

then I run my program, it print that

```
"libcjson.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

Comment: and what's the output of `ldd` for your program? If it's your own program, show code...

Comment: for safe, I run the program, which is libcurl offical test progarm, too.But the result is the same as before

Comment: I think , libcurl is on /usr/local/lib ,so ,I want to add this path to ldconfig config

Comment: Looks like `ln -S /path/to/libcjson.1.5.7 /path/to/libcjson.so` will fix it

Comment: /path/to/libcjson.1.5.7 is the symbolic link of libcjson.so ,so we could not link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last , I found that ***ldconfig*** default path is `/usr/lib`, but my dynamic library is in `/usr/local/lib`. So I add this path to ldconfig's config.

When we copy the library, we should get that some library just symbolic link. After copy to somewhere, it can not work normally.